# Is it possible to achieve the functionality of a Chromecast with an SBC?

Tags: sbc

Is it possible to achieve the functionality of a Chromecast with an SBC? Including the feature of screen casting from different devices?

Comment: Technically...the Chromecast itself is a SBC. The real problem lies more with the software that the chromecast uses. Pretty sure its proprietary.

Comment: @NatsuKage if Netflix doesn't even release ARM binaries, you can imagine the state of SBCs as HTPCs... And x86 SBCs are few and far between. Though I'm pretty sure you would be able to cast with an Android-capable SBC. Definitely not to it.

Comment: @NatsuKage Yes I can figure that that Chromecast is an SBC itself and it has to be. My point is can I get close to it with a different SBC (as in general) in terms of the functionalities, I have asked this question guessing the possibilities, to have a better idea in this regard.